# OOP Pygame Circle

Tags: python, oop, pygame, pygame-surface

I am creating a game and I need a ring created around the character. I have OOP written for creating a wall, seen below but I don't know how to adapt this code so that it can create a ring around my player.

```py
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
```

Also, variables I want to pass in are the colour, radius, width/thickness and x & y coordinates, e.g.

```
circle = Circle(colour, radius, width, x, y)
```

Drawing sprites edit:

```
spriteList.add(wallList)
spriteList.draw(screen)
```

Any help greatly appreciated,
Cheers

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle).

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to draw a circle around the player or around the wall? Is the player a sprite or just a rectangle? Do you use [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw)?

Comment: Around the player

Comment: @itstwalker I've asked more than 1 question.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Sorry, didn't see the rest. Player is a sprite and to draw them, I add all of the groups to a list and draw the group. Please see edit above on how they are drawn.

Comment: @itstwalker I've answered your question. You have to adapt the suggestions for your application. I can't guess your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circle can be drawn with [`pygame.draw.circle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle)

```py
pygame.draw.circle(surface, color, center, radius)
```

If you just want to draw a circular sprite, all you need to do is specify the radius and width (line thickness) of the circle:

```py
class Circle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, circleColor, radius, width, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface((radius * 2, radius * 2), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, circleColor, (radius, radius), radius, width)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
```

With this solution, you need to draw 2 objects, the sprite and the circle, separately at the same position.

However, if you want to create a single sprite object with a circle around it, you need to create a transparent surface that is larger than the sprite image. `blit` the sprite on the surface and draw a circle around it. In the following  `image` is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object:

```py
import math
```

```py
class MyPlayer(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, image, circleColor, width):
        super().__init__()
        
        diameter = math.hypot(*image.get_size())
        radius = diameter // 2

        self.image = pygame.Surface((diameter, diameter), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.blit(image, image.get_rect(center = (radius, radius))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, circleColor, (radius, radius), radius, width)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
```